# What does "empty nest" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

In [Black Widow (2021)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Widow_(2021_film)), Black Widow is on the ship. Inside the building, a soldier finds ladies washroom
empty and returns back to Ross:

> Soldier: Got an **empty nest**, Secretary Ross. Her tracker, sir.

What does "empty nest" mean in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that they didn't find her where she was expected to be.

There's a common metaphor in English that "the bird has flown", meaning the person you're looking for has disappeared or escaped. This is linked to that — the bird (Black Widow) has left her nest (the building they expected to find her in) so it's empty.

There is also an idiomatic meaning for "empty nest" which is a house where the adult children have moved out and only the parents are left, but that doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: Black Widow is not a bird.

Comment: It doesn't mean that she is literally a bird. It's a description — if a bird has left its nest, the nest will be empty. In this scenario, the woman has left the building, so the building is empty.