# What does the phrase "left the nest and started living on their own" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can the phrase "left the nest and started living on their own" be used metaphorically to mean something else from leaving one's parent's home to live on their own" in the following sentence?

*The idea of Bobby was born out of the real need for subscription management by one of the Yummygum team members that left the nest and started living on their own.* (Source: [Yummygum's website](https://yummygum.com/projects/bobby))

Comment: The phrase 'left the nest' here clearly means 'left the parental home to live independently'.  The site you linked to is for an app to help people manage their monthly subscription expenses. This is something that a newly independent young adult will need to do.

Comment: See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292339/what-does-empty-nest-mean-in-this-context?rq=1  In particular the alternate meaning "empty nest = home after children have left"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "empty nest" mean in this context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/292339/what-does-empty-nest-mean-in-this-context)

Comment: No, my confusion was that the nest might refer to something else than the parents' home.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly this.  "Leaving the nest" (or flying the nest etc) is a common metaphor for "leaving one's parental home and setting up a new household (perhaps in a different town).  [Here](https://questionablecontent.net/view.php?comic=5057) is an recent example:

> You spend all your life getting ready for your little ones to leave the nest [...] when the prospect finally arises, it stirs up a lot of emotions...

It could also be used literally of birds.

Comment: In the UK we often say that our children 'fly the nest', although that use of 'fly' might seem old-fashioned these days.